# Assigning values to a list of variables without using an if statement in Applescript

Tags: list, applescript

This question seems to have been covered before in other languages, but I can't seem to locate one in applescript. I'm making a script that allows me to bring up a menu and select a website to go to. I currently have it working, but it uses an if statement to go through every possible option to see if that's the one I chose -- you can see below:

```
    set theDestinations to {"Agorapulse", "Applescript Error Guide", "Budget Template", "Chinese Dictionary", "FNBG Email", "Key Codes", "Slacker", "Verbling - Chinese", "Verbling - Russian"} as list

set theChosenDestination to choose from list theDestinations with prompt "Where do you want to go?" default items {"Agorapulse"}

set theChosenDestination to (get item 1 of theChosenDestination)

tell application "System Events"
    if (theChosenDestination = "Agorapulse") then
        set theURL to "https://app.agorapulse.com/"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Applescript Error Guide") then
        set theURL to "http://krypted.com/lists/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Budget Template") then
        set theURL to "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4Yso2DgTbJq_c807_gQhuZBNa5sKtYc1VYEzHfZVnU/edit#gid=1442879437"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Chinese Dictionary") then
        set theURL to "https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=hedgehog"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "FNBG Email") then
        set theURL to "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/FNBGames"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Key Codes") then
        set theURL to "https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Slacker") then
        set theURL to "https://slacker.nathanhoad.net/fnbgames"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Verbling - Chinese") then
        set theURL to "https://www.verbling.com/lesson/5c9007a743a3330007554ad8"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Verbling - Russian") then
        set theURL to "https://www.verbling.com/lesson/5c9b354fd50da2000708901a"
    else if (theChosenDestination = "Other") then
        set theURL to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the URL of the target website:" default answer "")
    else
        display dialog "no match"
    end if
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location theURL
end tell
```

Like I said, it works, and given the light work it has to do it operates plenty fast, but it is *inelegant*. I look at that long list.

What I'd really like to be able to do is something like I've seen in other languages, something like a list of {("Agorapulse", "https://app.agorapulse.com"),(...)}, but I've fiddled about and can't seem to make it work. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

(oh, also, I had to beat the code about the head and shoulders a bit to get the list choices and the checks in the if statement to be of the same class so they'd talk to each other. I think I did an OK job of that, but feel free to critique :)

Answer (score 0):

Use two lists, adding the index prefix is more efficient.

```
set theDestinations to {"1 Agorapulse", "2 Applescript Error Guide", "3 Budget Template", "4 Chinese Dictionary", "5 FNBG Email", "6 Key Codes", "7 Slacker", "8 Verbling - Chinese", "9 Verbling - Russian", "10 Other…"}
set theURLs to {"https://app.agorapulse.com/", "http://krypted.com/lists/comprehensive-list-of-mac-os-x-error-codes/", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4Yso2DgTbJq_c807_gQhuZBNa5sKtYc1VYEzHfZVnU/edit#gid=1442879437", "https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=hedgehog", "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/FNBGames", "https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes", "https://slacker.nathanhoad.net/fnbgames", "https://www.verbling.com/lesson/5c9007a743a3330007554ad8", "https://www.verbling.com/lesson/5c9b354fd50da2000708901a"}

set theChosenDestination to choose from list theDestinations with prompt "Where do you want to go?" default items {"1 Agorapulse"}
if theChosenDestination is false then return
set chosenIndex to (word 1 of item 1 of theChosenDestination) as integer

if chosenIndex < 10 then
    set theURL to item chosenIndex of theURLs
else
    set theURL to text returned of (display dialog "Enter the URL of the target website:" default answer "")
end if
```

Comment: Very clever! Thanks so much!